# Django Crispy forms Submit does not work with TabHolder, but does work with field sets

Tags: python, django, tabs, django-crispy-forms

For some reason the Submit works fine with Fieldsets, but not with the Tabholder in  Django Crispy forms.
The tabs work fine, the conditional hiding of fields also works great. Just don't seem to be able to save any changes to the database. Any thoughts?

Hereby my code as I use for testing functionalities to improve my Django skills.

Models.py

```
class TestCondition(models.Model):
    some_name = models.ForeignKey(key_name, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    A_type_choices = (
        ('1','1'),
        ('2','2'),
    )
    Field_A = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices= A_type_choices,default='1')
    B_field_choices = (
        ('abc','ABC'),
        ('cba','CBA'),
    )
    Field_B = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices= B_field_choices,default='abc',blank=True,)
    Field_C = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default='')
    Field_D = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default='')
    Field_E = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default='')
```

Forms.py

```
class TestConditionTabForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestCondition
        fields = ('some_name','Field_A','Field_B','Field_C','Field_D','Field_E',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestConditionTabForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(form=self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            TabHolder(
            Tab(
                'Tab1',
                Field('some_name', type='hidden'),
                'Field_A','Field_B','Field_C',
            ),
            Tab(
                'Tab2',
                'Field_D',
            ),
            Tab(
                'Tab3',
                'Field_E',
            )),
        Fieldset(
            'Test Fieldset submit',
            Field('some_name', type='hidden'),
            'Field_A','Field_B','Field_C','Field_D','Field_E',
                ),

            )   
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('save', 'Submit'))
```

Views.py

```
class ViewUpdateTestForm(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = TestCondition
    template_name = 'test/update.html'
    form_class = TestConditionTabForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        model = form.save(commit=False)
        model.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('test:testds-overview', args=[model.some_name.id]))
```

Update.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-tab.js' %}">  </script>
     <script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}">  </script>
        <script>
    function Hide() {
        if(document.getElementById('id_Field_A').options[document.getElementById('Field_A').selectedIndex].value == "1") {
             document.getElementById('id_Field_B').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('id_Field_C').style.display = '';
        } else {
             document.getElementById('id_Field_B').style.display = '';
             document.getElementById('id_Field_C').style.display = 'none';
        }
    };  </script>
     {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
     {% crispy form form.helper%}


    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener("load", Hide);</script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var el = document.getElementById("div_id_weigth_type");
     el.addEventListener("click", Hide);</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ButtonHolder worked. Still no clue why, but lot's of trial and error.

```
ButtonHolder(
            Submit('save', 'Save'),
```